# Как получить тип view и layout, в который добавлен view

Tags: android, view

Есть `view`, вложенный в некий `layout`, и этот `view` в процессе работы приложения уничтожается.

Вместо уничтоженного `view` должен быть создан новый `view`, но такого же типа (*т.е. именно textview, если был уничтожен textview, а если бы уничтожался imageview, то должен был быть создан imageview*). Созданный `view` должен быть добавлен в тот же контейнер, в котором лежал уничтоженный `view`(т.е. нужно получить родительский контейнер удаленного `view`, чтобы добавить в него созданный `view`).

Я так понимаю процесс:

1. до уничтожения `view` нужно получить, какого он типа (т.е. это textView или иной) и получить родительский его контейнер
2. создать `view` и привести его к типу уничтоженного `view`
3. добавить `view` в контейнер, в котором лежал уничтоженный view.

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: А зачем столько манипуляций, если это тот же тип контрола? Не проще переиспользовать?

Comment: переиспользовать никак не получается, т.к. задействованы несколько видом анимации, и проще уничтожить один view и заменить его другим, чем переиспользовать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сохраните перед уничтожением класс этого `View`, получить можно так:

```
Class<? extends View> vClass = viewToDestroy.getClass();
```

Родительский ViewGroup получить тоже не составит труда:

```
ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) viewToDestroy.getParent();
```

Теперь когда понадобится создать новый объект того же типа:

```
View view = vClass.getConstructor(Context.class).newInstance(this);
```

И вернуть его на место:

```
viewGroup.addView(view);
```

Comment: Что-то на строку View view = vClass.getConstructor(Context.class).newInstance(this); ругается студия. Я с рефлексией вообще не знакома, не понимаю, в чем проблема. vClass возвращает android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView

Comment: Так наведите и посмотрите что говорит IDE. А говорит она обернуть в try/catch, на случай вылета исключения.